# How can I exclude an Array field from indexes in Google Datastore via nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I'm using Google Datastore and stuck with the size limit of 1500 bytes for indexed properties. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) mentions that the limit for unindexed properties is 1 MB - 89 bytes. I have the following structure:

```
    dataset = {
        property1: String,
        property2: String,
        property3: [
            {
                subProperty1: String,
                subProperty2: ArrayList<String>, // Larger than 1500 bytes
                excludeFromIndexes: true
            }   
        ]

}
```

That gives: **"Error: The value of property "subProperty2" is longer than 1500 bytes."**

It didn't work and I couldn't understand why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude an Array type property from indexes, each element within the array must have `excludeFromIndexes` set to `true`. The main Array property should **NOT** set `excludeFromIndexes`. When you edit an array property from GCD Console, the JSON for the array property should look like the one below:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "stringValue": "a", 
      "excludeFromIndexes": true
    },
    {
      "stringValue": "b", 
      "excludeFromIndexes": true
    },
    {
      "stringValue": "c",
      "excludeFromIndexes": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Also note that the length restriction of 1500 bytes is applied to each individual element of the array rather than for the whole array size. So you can really have long strings within the array and still be able to index, if you choose to do so.

Another thing to note is you don't have to exclude all elements of the array from indexing. You can pick and choose which elements can be indexed/not.

Not too familiar with Node.js, but there seems to be an example in the [API documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/1.1.0/datastore?method=save) (scroll a page or so in the #save section).

Comment: API documentation suggest using:
{
key: key,
data: data,
excludeFromIndexes: [
      'property3[].subProperty2[]'
]

But this also didn't work.
}