# GCP Datastore Node Library: Proper format for an object containing an array of long strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a JavaScript object of the following form:

```js
const data = {
  title: "short string",
  descriptions: [
    "Really long string...",
    "Really long string..."
  ]
}
```

The long strings need to be excluded from the indexes and, for whatever reason, I can't figure out what format the object needs to be to save it:

```js
const entityToSave = dataToDatastore(data);

datastore.save({
  key: datastore.key(["TestEntity"]),
  data: entityToSave
})
```

I simply need to know what `entityToSave` should look like. I've tried about twenty different shapes and every single attempt I've tried that uses `excludeFromIndexes` has either thrown an error saying the string was too large or ends up as an Entity type instead of an Array type.

I can get it to work via the GCP admin interface so I feel like I'm going crazy.

Edit: For convenience I am including a script that should run as long as you (1) set the `PROJECT_ID` and (2) add an appropriately long string to the `descriptions` array.

```js
const { Datastore } = require("@google-cloud/datastore");

const PROJECT_ID = null;

const data = {
  title: "short string",
  descriptions: [
    "Really long string...",
    "Really long string...",
  ]
}

const entityToSave = dataToDatastore(data);

async function save() {
  const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  });

  console.log(entityToSave);

  const entity = {
    key: datastore.key(["TestEntity"]),
    data: entityToSave
  };

  datastore.save(entity);
}

function dataToDatastore(data) {
  return data
}

save();
```

I simply need to know what `dataToDatastore` should look like. I've already tried numerous variations based on documentation and discussions from four or five different places and not one has worked.

Comment: As the Console is working fine, please raise an issue here : https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues

Answer (score -1):

You have to apply `excludeFromIndexes: true` to all entities in the array which is crossing the 1500 bytes limit.

```
const data = {
  title: "short string",
  descriptions: [
    "Really long string...",//> 1500 bytes
    "Really long string...", //> 1500 bytes
  ]
}
```

Here is how `entityToSave` should look like

```
const entityToSave = data.descriptions.map(description => ({
    value: description,
    excludeFromIndexes: true
  }));
console.log(entityToSave);

// this will transform data.descriptions to 
// [
//   { value: 'Really long string...', excludeFromIndexes: true },
//   { value: 'Really long string...', excludeFromIndexes: true }
// ]

Which will apply `excludeFromIndexes: true` to all entities 

//Then save the entity
datastore.save({
  key: datastore.key(["TestEntity"]),
  data: entityToSave
})
```

For more information check this [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2615) and [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45835683/18265570)

Comment: This does not work. First, the entire `data` object needs to be saved, not just the descriptions. Second, it is simply not valid code because there is no `name`.

Comment: Have you tried this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835683).

Comment: Yeah man, I spent four hours debugging this two days ago and got past all the references you're linking to in the first half hour. Taking random, unverified stabs at answering the question is not a productive use of anyone's time.

Comment: Here there are official examples provided in this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/HEAD/samples/concepts.js) for different use cases.

Comment: Is there an official example for the use case in the specific question I asked?

Comment: Unfortunately unable to find any examples. As @Gourav mentioned above in the comments try raising a [Github Issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues).